# MFMailComposeViewController is implemented but I still can't receive the mail

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

I'm excercising a sample code in "More iphone 3 Development Tackling iphone SDK 3" which called MailPic. Everything is fine. No error no warning.

```
- (IBAction)selectAndMailPic {
UIImagePickerControllerSourceType sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
      UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
}

UIImagePickerController *picker =
[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = sourceType;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}

```
- (void)mailImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailComposer setSubject:NSLocalizedString(@"Here's a picture...", @"Here's a picture...")];
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"image"];
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:NSLocalizedString(@"Here's a picture that I took with my iPhone.", @"Here's a picture that I took with my iPhone.") isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
        [mailComposer release];
        [image release];
    }
    else 
        message.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Can't send e-mail...", @"Can't send e-mail...");
}
```

sending mail is good but I still can't receive it. What did I miss?
sending mail is good but I still can't receive it. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*MFMailComposeViewController* doesn't actually sends the mail. It just queues the mail in the *Mail* app's *Outbox*, nothing more. You check the *Mail* app's *Outbox* and see whether the mail is actually sent or not.

There may be some problem with the internet connectivity in your phone. In the worst case, resending the mail from *Mail* app's *Outbox* may help you!

Comment: Oh, That is the reason. Thank you. BTW, May I ask is there possible to send email completely in-app?

Comment: I only use the simulator but there is no Mail app in it.

Comment: Oh! You can't send mail from simulator ;-) Test it in a real device!

Answer (score 0):

MFMailComposer is only for sending mails not for receiving mails. You need to read class reference of MFMailComposer.

Answer (score 0):

This app is work on iphone or real time device not on simulator.